# BUILD LOGIC - what could be better than using AWK?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

Below is how a log looks like:

```
Company=XYZ
Req_id=1234
Time_taken=10 sec
Status=Success

Company=ABC
Req_id=3456
Time_taken=200 sec
Status=Failure

Company=DFG
Req_id=3001
Time_taken=15 sec
Status=Success
```

We have to get top 3 request IDs where max time is taken.

I tried with below solution where I get request id and time taken but I am not happy with my answer:

```sh
awk -vRS= -F'[=\n]' '/Time_taken/{print $4,$6}' test.txt | sort -nr
```

How could I have done this better? Use some logic to code instead of inbuilt functions. Also, I need to understand `-F'[=\n]'` better? I have been just copying it from my previous scripts.

Output should be:

```
Below Request Id took more then expected
Request id 3456, Time Taken 200 sec
Request id 3001, Time Taken 15 sec  
Request id 1234, Time Taken 10 sec
```

Comment: I have edited my question with what i require. Please help to get this offhold.

Comment: You've got my reopen vote, hopefully others will follow (5 are required). Please, write "I" always with capital letter.

Comment: I cast the last required open vote. I’ve also edited to remove the syntax highlighting of the input and output. I’ve also upvoted it because it’s now a useful, clear question that shows what you’ve already tried or researched.  For future questions, I’d recommend reading [ask] and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5015/22812

Answer (score 2):

Using only `awk`:

```
function list_insert (value, id, tmp) {
    for (i = 1; i <= list_length; ++i)
        if (value > value_list[i]) {
            tmp = value_list[i]
            value_list[i] = value
            value = tmp

            tmp = id_list[i]
            id_list[i] = id
            id = tmp
        }
}

BEGIN {
    FS = "[= ]"
    list_length = 3
}

$1 == "Req_id"     { id = $2 }
$1 == "Time_taken" { list_insert($2, id) }

END {
    printf("Below Request Id took more then expected\n")
    for (i = 1; i <= list_length; ++i)
        printf("Request id %d, time taken %d sec\n", id_list[i], value_list[i])
}
```

This program maintains two arrays, `value_list` and `id_list`, both of length `list_length`.  The `value_list` array is sorted and contains the time values, while the `id_list` array contains the request IDs corresponding to the values in the first list.

The `list_insert` function inserts a new value and ID into the two arrays in such a way that the order of the `value_list` array is maintained (it finds the correct location for insertion and then shuffles the remaining items towards the end).

The rest of the program reads the data as newline-delimited records of fields delimited by `=` or spaces.  When a request ID is found, this is saved in `id`, and when a "time taken" entry is found, that ID and the time take value are inserted into the arrays.

At the end, the two arrays are used to create the output.

Testing it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
Below Request Id took more then expected
Request id 3456, time taken 200 sec
Request id 3001, time taken 15 sec
Request id 1234, time taken 10 sec
```

Comment: You just blowed off my mind !!! Can you help with why you have set list_length = 3? and why its required to have insert_list function ? What solution @Archemar gave below is not better ?

Comment: @Machine I would not say my solution is better or worse than any other's. I'm assuming that there may be more than three records in the in-data, and I use `list_length = 3` to get the top three results. The `list_insert` function adds data to the arrays that the program maintains, while always keeping the top three. This kind of combines the `sort` and `head` that Archemar is doing as post-processing steps.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using the paragraph mode of `Perl` wherein we read in paragraph sized chunk of files as records and build up a hash keyed on IDs and values as time taken. At the end of file, we reverse sort numerically on the times taken and then print the desired message.

```
$ perl -ln -00 -e '
    %h = (%h, /^Req_id=(\d+)\n.*^Time_taken=(\d+)/ms)}{
    print "The below IDs took more than expected:" if scalar keys %h;
    print join " ", "Req ID:", "$_," , "Time taken", $h{$_}, "sec"
       for (sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a}  } keys %h)[0..2];
' input.file
```

Output:

```
The below IDs took more than expected:
Req ID: 3456, Time taken 200 sec
Req ID: 3001, Time taken 15 sec
Req ID: 1234, Time taken 10 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remember request number.

I would use (this could be one lined)

```
awk -F= '$1 == "Req_id" {r=$2 ; } 
   $1 == "Time_taken" { printf "Request id %s %s %s\n",r,$1,$2 ; }' file |
sort -r -n -k5 |
head -3
```

which give

```
Request id 3456 Time_taken 200 sec
Request id 3001 Time_taken 15 sec
Request id 1234 Time_taken 10 sec
```

where

- `-F=` use `=` as separator
- `$1 == "Req_id" {r=$2 ; }` get last request id
- `$1 == "Time_taken"` if line is "time taken"
- `{ printf "Request id %s %s %s\n",r,$1,$2 ; }` print request id and seconds
- `| sort` pipe to sort
- `-r` reverse order
- `-n` numeric sort (e.g. 200 greater than 15)
- `-k5` on 5th field
- `| head -3` get first 3 lines

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer Python over awk for anything except one-liners. Using a Python script will allow you to more easily handle poorly formatted input and to perform logging and error-handling.

Here is a basic Python script that will produce the desired output for your example input, and which has a structure which is suggestive of how you might build it out further if needed:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""parse_log.py"""

import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

logfilepath = sys.argv[1]

# Define a function to parse a single block/entry in the log file
def parse_block(block):
    parsed_block = dict()
    lines = block.split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("Company="):
            parsed_block["Company"] = line[8:]
        elif line.startswith("Req_id="):
            parsed_block["Required_ID"] = line[7:]
        elif line.startswith("Time_taken="):
            parsed_block["Time_Taken"] = line[11:]
        elif line.startswith("Status="):
            parsed_block["Status"] = line[7:]
        else:
            pass
    return parsed_block

# Initialize a list to store the processed entries
parsed_blocks = list()

# Populate the list
with open(logfilepath, "r") as logfile:
    blocks = logfile.read().split("\n\n")
    for block in blocks:
        parsed_block = parse_block(block)
        parsed_blocks.append(parsed_block)

# Print the results
print("Below Request Id took more then expected")
for parsed_block in parsed_blocks:
    print("Request id {}, Time Taken: {}".format(parsed_block["Required_ID"], parsed_block["Time_Taken"]))
```

You could run it like this:

```py
python parse_log.py data.log
```

On your example input, it produces the following output (as requested):

```
Below Request Id took more then expected
Request id 1234, Time Taken: 10 sec
Request id 3456, Time Taken: 200 sec
Request id 3001, Time Taken: 15 sec
```